# Php: Work with time() and date()

Tags: php

I need a help!! I need to output the current time (12:00:00) and the time to 30 minutes earlier (11:30:00).
I used function `date()` with parameters `date("H:i:s")`, but i didn`t know how cut 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();

echo 'Current time is: ' . $dateTime->format('H:i:s') . '<br />';

$dateTime->modify('-30 minutes');

echo 'Modified time is: ' . $dateTime->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: it`s work, but when i want to append to string show error [Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string]

Comment: you can concatenate the result of `format` method: `$myString = "This is my date" .  $dateTime->format('H:i:s');`

Answer (score 0):

Current time:

```
date("H:i:s", time());
```

Time 30 minutes before:

```
date("H:i:s", time()-(60*30));
```

The date() function takes a second argument the timestamp of the time that you wanna format, if you provide none, it uses the current timestamp as the default parameter.